# What's good form for calling views within a module (template, etc)?

Tags: views

I have about three views that will be used; Here's [Daniel Wehner's](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/8306/5569) answer:

```
 $view = views_get_view(); 
 $view->set_display();
 $view->filter['foo']->value = 'bar'; 
 print $view->preview($display_id, $args);
```

I built this based off his code, which while works, could be improved if including views is going to be a regular activity throughout your project:

```
$view = views_get_view('nodequeue_3');
$view->set_display();

$content['raw_markup'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => $view->preview(),
);
```

<strike>I'm also thinking this might not be done that often, because if you can build a module, why use views?</strike>

The utility of views should not be overlooked, in combination with (or without) a custom module.

Thanks for the patience, this community is awesome!

Comment: Try views_embed_view()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prever to use this small helper function:

```
function mymodule_embed_view($view_id, $display_id, $arguments) {
    $view = views_get_view($view_id);
    $view->set_display($display_id);
    $view->set_arguments($arguments);
    $view->pre_execute();
    $view->execute();
    return $view->render();
}
```